# NodeJS using module's module instead of project's module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, react-typescript

Trying to use a specific version of a node module (v0.2.0) in my own project, but one of my dependencies requires v0.1.8 of the same module. No issue, I thought, that dependency will use v0.1.8 in its nested `node_modules` folder and my app will use v0.2.0 in my project's `node_modules` folder. I added v0.2.0 as a dependency to my `package.json` and ran `npm install` again. However, for some reason my app points to the other dependency's v0.1.8 module (in its nested `node_modules`) when I ctrl-click it, instead of the expected v0.2.0 module correctly installed in the project's own `node_modules` folder. Here's the code I'm using to import from the modules (@metaplex/js relies on v0.1.8 of @solana/spl-token, while I need to use v0.2.0 of @solana/spl-token in my own app):

```
import { ... } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { ... } from '@metaplex/js';
```

I verified that the v0.1.8 spl-token was installed in `./node_modules/@metaplex/js/node_modules/@solana/spl-token`, and the v0.2.0 spl-token was installed in `./node_modules/@solana/spl-token`. I also ran `npm ls @solana/spl-token` to make sure it was in the dependency tree, and here are the results:

```
├─┬ @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@1.2.5
│ └── @solana/spl-token@0.1.8
├─┬ @metaplex/js@4.12.0
│ ├─┬ @metaplex-foundation/mpl-auction@0.0.2
│ │ └── @solana/spl-token@0.1.8
│ ├─┬ @metaplex-foundation/mpl-metaplex@0.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata@0.0.2
│ │ │ └── @solana/spl-token@0.1.8 deduped
│ │ └── @solana/spl-token@0.1.8
│ ├─┬ @metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-vault@0.0.2
│ │ └── @solana/spl-token@0.1.8
│ └── @solana/spl-token@0.1.8
└── @solana/spl-token@0.2.0
```

I can't figure out why my code still imports from the wrong version used by another dependency when I installed the correct version in my project's `node_modules` folder. Is there a workaround or solution to solve this?

*fairly new to node, sorry*

Edit: (my project is a typescript react project) did some more poking around and apparently, v0.1.8 of the module's `package.json`'s `types` property points to an `*.d.ts` file like this:

```
declare module '@solana/spl-token' {

  export //functions, fields, etc

}
```

while v0.2.0's `package.json`'s `types` property points to a simple `*.d.ts` file like

```
export * from './instructions/index';
...
```

(note there is no specific `declare` keyword for the module itself)
and each function has a separate `*.d.ts` where the specific member is `declare`d, as such in `functionName.d.ts`:

```
export declare function functionName(...): Promise<...>;
```

I don't know if this change causes some type of namespace conflict but it seems like this is a very specific error having to do with this particular module and not something generally wrong with node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by very specific error ?

This Is very common issue
At yow tsconfig.json set the `baseUrl` AND `paths`

```
{
...
"baseUrl":"./node_modules",
"paths":{
"name-of-the-package":[
   "relative-to-baseurl/position/where/yow-code-is"
]
}}
```

The position of yow code Is relative to baseUrl.

Comment: looks like I looked into it a little too much... looks like this fixed it, but it's weird that `create-react-app`'s typescript template doesn't automatically include this if it's so necessary. thanks regardless!

Comment: Create react app creates a `react-env.d.ts` for you to add your pen types. Your real problem Is the multi version thingy you should only work with one versión